# Setting a default / initial value for Ink Filepicker Widget

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm using the [Ink Filepicker widget](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick) to allow users to select images. Many images are found via the *'Web Images'* or *Link (URL)* option.

I want to be able to pass in (likely via a `data-fp-` type attribute) options that mean the FilePicker dialog goes straight to the *Link (URL)* source and pre-fills the image URL I provide, so the user doesn't always have to select an image. They can override it if necessary.

The reason I am not setting a default on the server side after POST of the form is that the default image will be set dynamically when the form is loaded.

Is there any way to do this on the client side? Or do I need to do a server-side kludge to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add data-fp-openTo option.
E.g.
    data-fp-openTo='/Imagesearch/lolcats'

Check out documentation https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick

Comment: The documentation mentions openTo but doesn't add the additional paramater eg /lolcats/. Thanks for the suggestion!